# Getting error when using forecast function in R

Tags: r, forecasting

Getting this error while using forecast function

```r
fc<-forecast(fit, h=18)
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'dummy[, 3]')
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 18 rows but variables found have 126 rows '
```

I am using the `seasonaldummy()` function to create the seasonal dummy variables and then finding the fit using the `tslm()` function. I am doing this as i have to drop a few insignificant seasons for my monthly data consisting of 126 months and I have no way to drop it from the the normal `data~trend+season`

Expecting the forecasts but getting the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.